# canvas element seems to be disabled

Tags: canvas, element

I've used a canvas element to show a map with patches that are colored according to values obtained from a MySQL query and written into a javascript array. It works fine on my two computers, in Firefox 4, IE 9, and Safari. But when I did a demo at school, with both IE 8 (maybe that would be a problem) and Firefox 3.6 (should work) the canvas was not visible. I can't see any way it can even be disabled! What have the IT guys at the school done, and how can I test for it and draw a regular image map instead?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't support canvas. You can use [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) to emulate it.

Second, IIRC, browsers are not obliged to set canvas width and height to any value. You may try to set `width` and `height` attributes.

UPD: It will be nice if you provide a fragment of your page. Before you do this, some ideas on how to narrow problem.

- Ensure that your page doctype is set to `<!doctype html>`.
- Ensure that no messages about `canvas` being not supported (i.e. text put between `<canvas>` and `</canvas>`) are displayed (it shouldn't happen with Firefox 3.6, but nevertheless).
- Set `style='border:solid;'` for your canvas element. Check if border is drawn at expected position.
- Enclose `canvas` into `div` element and make sure it is displayed at expected position (e.g. by setting `style='border:solid;'` for it as well).

If border for canvas and/or wrapping element is displayed but there's no drawing, then there's some error with drawing code. If it is not then there's problem with element positioning (e.g. CSS went wild) or loading document per se.

UPD: I ran site with Firebug enabled and it shown an exception at `drawImage` call.

```
img.src = 'images/snap9.jpg';
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  // HERE!
```

But only for the first load of page in the browser session.

The reason is (I guess) that when you set `src` to image address, it is not loaded immediately, and drawing it impossible until then. So exeption is thrown and the rest of coded is not executed.

You should set `onload` handler for images (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)) and do the rest of drawing in this handler.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not interested in IE -- my users use Firefox, and the canvas doesn't work there either. I do set width and height in the html that creates the element (not in javascript).

Comment: Thanks elder_george. I put the text inside the canvas and it doesn't show. I got a reply from the IT security at the college and he says they don't do anything to disable HTML 5 stuff. The site is:

Comment: the relevant pages are under Reports. the middle 3 pages are maps that have colored patches that are clickable. I want the colors to reflect values fetched from the database.

Comment: Wow. great advice. I think this might fix it, tho I can't test it until I get on campus and at a computer there. Took me a while to get all the "(" and "}" things straightened out, but this may fix the thing. Thanx elder_george.